# xcode - Extracting text from html code

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an app which reads data from SharePoint list into an array.  I am at the point of displaying this data on screen as text fields.   However one of the imported data fields is formatted in html markup code e.g.

`&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClass7E8EC81DFF944C7BB81DA896086ABDFF&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:12pt&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Calibri&quot;&gt;Project Completion Date (A05-A07) &lt;span&gt;  &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;  &lt;/span&gt;15&lt;sup&gt;th&lt;/sup&gt; May 2012&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#13;&#10;​ &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`

Does anyone know how I could go about extracting the text content from this?  Alternatively perhaps I should be looking at displaying this data as a web page on screen?  If so could someone point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML as posted is encoded with "entity" codes.  So, the first task is to decode those to get back to actual HTML.  You can use `CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities()` for that.

You can create an NSXMLDocument from the result with the NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML option.  You can request the `-stringValue` of that to get the plain text.

Alternatively, you can create an NSAttributedString with `-initWithHTML:documentAttributes:`.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I have decided to go down the display as a web page route, using 'loadHTMLString'. I have passed the previously mentioned data through to a new view, but it is displaying as html and not rendering as a web page.  Any clues how I can render it correctly from this point?  Thank you.

Comment: OK I have finally sorted it - using MREntitiesConverter to decode HTML to remove entities, and then loadHTMLString to render the pure html code on the screen as a web page.